# JQuery Modal - Hidden Div's vs Partial Views (MVC3)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, modal-dialog, partial-views

I am creating a website using MVC3/C#/ASP.NET which contains a view page that will show a JQuery Modal type popup (the implementation is a bit different than a traditional modal window, but the functionality is quite similar). Currently I have the markup that will go into the modal window stored as a partial view (with a separate associated model).

I was doing a little research on JQuery modal windows, and it seems a lot of the examples I am seeing online are using a single view with a hidden div, and the modal window is just populated with the markup from inside the hidden div. In these examples there is only one view (the main view for the page), and the model data behind the hidden div's input fields (etc) are just stored in the model associated with the main view (as opposed to having a separate view and model for the markup I want to display, as would be the case if I were to use a partial view implementation scheme).

*I was wondering if anyone can give some insight as to which method is preferred or what the standard practice is (if any) on this. Is this just a matter of personal preference? Is one way more efficient than the other?*

**Which way should I be doing this:**

- **A Partial View for the modal window markup with a separate view/model**
- **A Hidden Div within the existing view/model**

Note: I am working as part of a development team, so keeping things aligned with standard practice is very important.

Any thoughts on this matter would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

**Edit**: I asked my fellow developers who are on the same project how they were doing things similar to this. It looks like no matter how much I debate this issue with them, they all seem to agree that the "*best*" and "*most efficient way*" to do this is to render partial views, each with a separate model. I really do not understand why they all think that this method is any more efficient than using hidden divs, but since I am currently "the new guy" I did not push the issue too much and basically just pretended to agree with the point they were trying to make about efficiency.

TL;DR : I am now using partial views, whether I like it or not. I would still like to hear some more opinions on this though.

Comment: I would think it depends on the content of the Modal window. If the content is defined by the "page" itself, i would think its smarter to have it together. So that you can't have the page without the modal content. If the content on the other hand is used for dynamic content, which isnt page specific i would seperate it, so that it can be edited without worrying about changes in the parent. I guess it comes down to dependency in my head. Are they a requirement for each other, or can the page exist without the modal, and can the modal exist without the page.

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen In terms of dependancy, the main page cannot exist without the modal (it is a key part of the functioanlity on that page). However, I suppose that the modal could exist without the page.

Comment: Well if you are not going to reuse the Modal, i would put it into the page itself, since there is no reason for splitting up something just for sake of splitting it up. Ofcourse if the data is non-depedant on the page, it could have a point, since working on the partial wouldnt effect the page and the other way around (which is usable when working in teams). But if it has no function in other pages, and this page is required to include it, i would merge them. :)

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen I totally agree with you that there is no real reason behind splitting it into a seperate partial view. Regardless, if you check out my edit above, you will see that I have to use partial views for this because "it is more efficient that way" *rolls eyes*

Comment: What conclusion do they use for having partial views? Maybe i could learn something :) Being the new guy at my work, i know how your feeling!

Comment: @MarcoJohannesen
I have learned now that it is better (usually) to use partial views in this type of situation because it is easier for other people to simply implement the existing partial view into their own code later on if they need to use the same exact functionality. In general its the re-usability (sp?) issue that drives most devs on my team to use partial views (even if we know that they won't be re-used, it is still encouraged "just in case"

Comment: hehe... Well i guess some of the arguments hold - you never know when your code is going to be reused, what changes in the future - so i guess the point is always to make it as free and sepereate as possible (seems like the old OOP objective) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the partial view for Modal Dialog, the partial view will remain inside page HMTL DOM even if the modal is closed. I suggest to use separate views for modal pop up and call it using ajax methods.

Partial view method:

```
<div id="popup_window" title="Pop up title" >

<% Html.RenderPartial("_partialviewname", Model); %>

</div>
```

Next method using ajax

Html:

```
<div id="popup_window" title="Pop up title" > <!-- div to render the popup -->
</div>



<a onclick="javascript:ShowPopUp();" >Click here</a> <!--pop up is given by this link-->
```

Ajax function part

```
function ShowPopup(

$("#popup_window").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
               // height: 'auto',

                //width: 565
            });

     $.ajax({

                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/controller/action', //action to return view 
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#popup_window").empty();
                        $("#popup_window").append(data);





                    }
                });

                $(""#popup_window").dialog("open");
}
```

Comment: This method is pretty dependent that the modal window isnt a requirment on the page, if javascript is disabled etc. Accessibility is thrown out the window then. The whole reason is you load it into the DOM and hide it with JS, is that the use shouldnt be JS dependant.

Comment: this is more or less what I ended up doing. Thanks, I will mark this as the answer (eventhough I still think it is just a matter of preference when it comes down to it)

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is about a year old now, but I wanted to chime in with an answer.

You can roll your eyes all you want but remember you're the junior developer and the other guys in the office might actually know what they're talking about.

Ask yourself, why would I populate a hidden div with a bunch of data that the end user might never even use?  Unless they are opening the dialog every time they go to this page (if they are, there is something else fundamentally wrong with the page), it is "more efficient" to not render all of that data into the DOM.  The most efficient thing to do is to load the dialog with a partial view and pull the data only when the user requests to see it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Well, sorry for my misunderstand. If you can reuse, if you'll end up switch to AJAX based refresh or simply want to have a clean/simple main view, then go with the partials.

There's another way in MVC 3, that's to use EditorTemplates/DisplayTemplates. They're really powerfull, but require a bit of digging in to be used fully.
Both approach have pros and cons, it really depends on what you're specifically doing.

So long I've found two ways of displaying partial views in jqUI Dialogs.

The former is loading the view via AJAX or `@Html.RenderAction` 
The Latter, when scenario is pretty static, is to use the `@Html.RenderPartial` directly inside the div used for building the dialog.

Here's the Ajax method I use:

```
function MyDlg(options,bottoni) {
    var name = options.name;
    $(name).load(options.url, function () {
        var $jQval = $.validator;
        $jQval.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
        $(name).dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            width: options.width,
            heigth: options.height,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            title: options.title,
            modal: true,
            buttons: bottoni
        });
        $(name).dialog("open");
    });
}
```

As you can see, it receives something like:

```
var bottoni = {
    "Cancel": function () {
        // cancel pressed
    },
    "Ok": function () {
        // Ok pressed
    }
}
MyDlg({ name: "Edit", width: "auto", height: "auto", title: 'Edit Stuff', url: mvcUrl }, bottoni);
```

The important parts are:

the Unobtrusive activation:

```
var $jQval = $.validator;
$jQval.unobtrusive.parse($(this));
```

And the fact that the dialog is opened in the `load` event.

In the controller you simply return a `PartialView("_viewName", model)`.

Beware when using dialog, to clean 'em up. I prefer to programmatically create the div via document.createElement() and then remove it from DOM upon Closure, but there are scenarios in which I have to leave the div in the dom.

Comment: I appreciate your answer in terms of how to display partial views, but this is not really what I was asking. Basically what I want to know is which is better: using partial views, or hidden divs (for the actual markup inside the modal/dialog).

Comment: thanks for the edit, I will do some research on the EditorTemplates/DisplayTemplates method to carry this out.